# reactjs - sidebar not working after store update

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-redux, core-ui

I am using reactjs.
node: version 14

I am developing on core-ui-react-template.

Sidebar did not work after updating the ./store file. I put the contents of the store file and index.js file below.

original website core.io
I have been working on it for a few days but I could not get any results. I couldn't find where was the mistake

[image: core-ui-react-template SIDEBAR not working]

**index.js**

```
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11'; // For IE 11 support
import 'react-app-polyfill/stable';
import './polyfill'
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import { icons } from './assets/icons'
import store from './store'
import { transitions, positions, Provider as AlertProvider } from 'react-alert'
import AlertTemplate from 'react-alert-template-basic'
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import ReactNotification from 'react-notifications-component';
import 'react-notifications-component/dist/theme.css'

React.icons = icons;

const options = {
  position: positions.BOTTOM_RIGHT,
  timeout: 5000,
  offset: '1px',
  transition: transitions.SCALE,
};

console.log(store.getState());

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>

      <AlertProvider template={AlertTemplate} {...options}>

        <ReactNotification/>
        <App/>

      </AlertProvider>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

**./store.js**

```
import {applyMiddleware, combineReducers, compose, createStore} from "redux";
import customerReducer from "./components/helpers/reducers/customerReducer";
import userReducer from "./components/helpers/reducers/userReducer";
import appointmentsReducer from "./components/helpers/reducers/appointmenstReducer";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";


const initialState = {
  sidebarShow: 'responsive'
};

const changeStateReducer = (state = initialState, { type, ...rest }) => {
  switch (type) {
    case 'set':
      return {...state, ...rest };
    default:
      return state
  }
};
const rootReducers = combineReducers({
  customerInfo: customerReducer,
  account_profile: userReducer,
  appointmentsList: appointmentsReducer,
  changeState: changeStateReducer
});
const allEnhancers = compose(
  applyMiddleware(thunk)
);
const store = createStore(
  rootReducers,
  allEnhancers
);
export default store
```

As you know, I use core-ui-react template. There is a link below.
But after updating the ./store file, it shows "undefined" when I show it with console.log (sidebarShow) in "**const sidebarShow = useSelector (state => state.sidebarShow)**" line in TheHeader file.

https://github.com/coreui/coreui-free-react-admin-template/blob/master/src/containers/TheHeader.js

I think "**useSelector (state => state.sidebarShow)**" doesn't get the function here. It originates from here.

Comment: In the days you worked on it did you try to debug? In your question I don't see what the problem is with the side bar, what you expect it to do, how you come to expect it to do that, (if based on actions) what actions are dispatched and what changes to the state they made (redux dev tools) and (if side bar depends on redux state) what selectors it is using and if it got the props correctly.

Comment: I updated the question. I think I found the problem. But I couldn't find a solution.
When I press the sidebar button, "useSelector" sees it as "undefined".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check out how combineReducers works: https://redux.js.org/api/combinereducers

your selector should be:

```
const sidebarShow = useSelector(state => state.changeState.sidebarShow)
```

you'll notice that `changeState` is not a very good key name, but that is another issue :)

Comment: Hi,

I have worked with react-redux before. As you said, I edited the code. but again the sidebar does not work. Attached in the screenshot for redux.

https://ibb.co/C7mtYR8

Comment: so the state.changeStateMenu status is changing now, but the menu doesn't open and close

Comment: I found the problem. It worked when I edited the state.changeState.sidebarShow variable in TheSidebar.js. Thank you